# BIOS Parameter Block and disk formatting

Tags: assembly, bootloader, bootstrapping

I have written a simple bootloader of my own. I, first, have initial typical 3 lines of code

```
bits   16
org    0x7c00
jmp    main
```

followed by BIOS Parameter Block for FAT 12 and for 1.44MB Floppy disk, up to offset byte 0x003D. Let's say the main bootloader is printing "Hello World" for simplicity.

When I copy my bootloader using

```
PARTCOPY 0 200 -f0 0
```

it makes my disk to lose its format, triggering "Disk not formatted" message on Windows.

On the other hand, if I copy my bootloader using

```
PARTCOPY  0  3  -f0  0
PARTCOPY 3E 1C2 -f0 3E       ; Do not copy BIOS Parameter Block
```

Windows does not complain about the formatting.

With these different results, I would like to know how BPB affects the formatting and/or Partition Table.  I mentioned Partition Table, because I got an advice that I need to have the Partition Table to resolve the "Disk not formatted" problem after copying the boot sector.

Any help or comment would be appreciated.

Sincerely,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows performs a number of checks on boot sectors and is a little too picky in what it considers a valid boot sector. If you preserve the first 62 (0x3E) bytes of a FAT12 formatted floppy and don't corrupt the FAT, Windows won't complain. It doesn't care about what's in bytes at offsets 0x3E through 0x1FD. You can change the `OEM name` and `volume label name` entries too. The rest, just keep it as-is. Your code may use the values in the BPB to read a file from the FAT.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the clear answer. It simply tells me that I don't have "correct" BPB on my code. Do you know any reference/link I can look up and learn from?  Searching "FAT12 BPB" didn't give me much...

Comment: Read the BPB bytes from a formatted floppy. Or find a bootable 1.44" DOS/Win9x floppy image online and extract the BPB bytes from there.

Comment: You might want to try this [document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463080) from Microsoft it is pretty much the go to on FAT. I know it says FAT32 but it includes details for FAT12 and FAT16 as well.

Comment: @CharlesKeepax: great doc, true.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be missing a [Master Boot Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record), this should be placed in the first physical sector of the device and will be executed by the bios, it should transfer control to your boot loader. Although to be fair if you are putting your boot loader in a FAT partition you can probably just leave the MBR that would be created by formating the drive and copy your code directly into the location for active FAT partition rather than directly onto the start of the drive.

Microsoft also have a good explaination of the boot process on a FAT device [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140418), which might help.

Comment: For hard disk drive, BIOS loads Master Boot Record, which is the first sector of HDD. Then, MBR loads the boot sector according to the partition table. (Thanks to your link) Given that information, am I writing "Boot Loader" or "Master Boot Record" ? I am so confused ...

Comment: There's no MBR on floppies, it's for HDDs only.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Then, my main question is still valid I guess :)

Comment: Apologies the FAT12 stuff was edited into the question after my answer so I didn't know this was for a floppy at the time.